# Long Polling to update DOM while conserving accumulated attributes from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

**EDIT: Everything works; the pushes work. The only problem is that on each push the #load_info `div` is reset to empty. How can I preserve the original content inside the `div`, though the content would be the updated version of itself as the XML file is re-pushed.**

I have a PHP script for long polling an XML file and encoding it as a JSON array. It is called from frontend with the JSON as the parameter.

```
    $filename= dirname(__FILE__)."/people.xml";

    $lastmodif = isset( $_GET['timestamp'])? $_GET['timestamp']: 0 ;
    $currentmodif=filemtime($filename);

    while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif) {
        usleep(10000);
        clearstatcache();
        $currentmodif =filemtime($filename);
    }

    $response = array();
    $xObj = simplexml_load_file($filename);

    // Loop for #loadMe.
    foreach($xObj as $person){
        $concat_buttons .= "<button class='mybutton' value='" . (string)$person->id . " '> " . (string)$person->fullName . "</button>";
    }

    // Loop for #toadMe.
    foreach($xObj as $person){
        $concat_info .= "<div class='div div_' data-person-id='" . (string)$person->id . "' id='" . (string)$person->id . "'><h1> " . (string)$person->job . "</h1></div>";
    }


    // Output for AJAX.
    $response['msg']                = $concat_buttons;
    $response['msg2']                = $concat_info;
    $response['timestamp']      = $currentmodif;
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Then I have a jQuery script for instancing the JSON object (`msg2`) for appending each node into a `div` called `#load_data`. My question is why is the jQuery below not working? My guess is either the `$(window).find` isn't working in the `get_person(id)` function and/or my functions are out of scope with the polling. To note, the PHP and JS were 100% working before I started trying to incorporate the `show_person()` and `get_person()` functions. Working as in, when a certain button inside the `#load_button` `div` was clicked it would toggle a piece of information's view with an `id` that matched the button's `value` attribute with `.show()`, which was initially hidden; then if another button was clicked the old info would be hidden with `.hide()` and the new data would be seen. This was my round-about solution for using long-polling to update DOM elements by just loading them all up in the beginning, however if a piece of information is shown while a new poll occurs (`var` `timestamp` gets updated), then the elements inside of `#load_info` will temporarily get lost from the DOM, therefore resulting in an empty `#load_info` `div` until the next button is clicked. So am trying to add some additional functions to store DOM data inside the `var` `$person` so that after a poll whatever was shown prior would reappear. What can be changed or added to get this jQuery script working as intended? Thanks in advance!

```
    var timestamp=null;
    function waitForMsg() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getData.php?timestamp="+timestamp,
            async: true,
            cache: false,        
            success: function(data) {
                var json=eval('('+data+ ')');
                if (json['msg'] != "") {
                    $("#load_buttons").empty();
                    $("#load_buttons").append(json['msg']);

                    // Update any person divs that were already visible.
                    $('#load_info .person').each(function() {
                        // Grabs the ID from data-person-id set earlier.
                        var id = $(this).data('person-id');
                        show_person(id);
                    });

                }
                timestamp = json["timestamp"];
                setTimeout("waitForMsg()",1000);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                setTimeout("waitForMsg()",15000);
            }                   
        });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function() {
        $('#load_info').empty();
        show_person(this.value);
    });

    function show_person(id) {
        $('#person-detail-' + id).remove();
        get_person(id).appendTo('#load_info');
    }

    function get_person(id) {
        var $person = $(window).find('id:contains(id)');

        var $div = $('<div>', {
            'class': 'person',
            'data-person-id': id,
            id: id
        });

        $person.find(h1).text.appendTo($div);
        return $div;  
    }
```

Comment: What is your intention with `$(window).find('id:contains(id)');`?

Comment: @Kyle Kyle, I'm trying to use it as a means to create a variable for recording the current element(s) inside the `#load_info` container therefore the variable can be used to re-show the element(s) that was/were shown prior to next push; if anything was shown prior, post button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question fairly difficult to understand, but I like a challenge. As a note, I haven't tested any of this code so it would need to be debugged.

Now, as I understand it, you have a bunch of buttons with this structure:

```
<div id="load_buttons">
  // repeater
  <button class="mybutton" value="$person['id']">$person['fullName']</button>
  // end repeater
</div>
```

And a bunch of detail divs with this structure, which are initially hidden:

```
<div id="load_info">
  // repeater
  <div class="div div_" data-person-id="$person['id']" id="$person['id']">
    <h1>$person['job']</h1>
  </div>
  // end repeater
</div>
```

And these should get updated/appended on every poll.

What you would like to achieve: when a button is clicked, the associated info is shown. I would do your success function like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var json=eval('('+data+ ')');
    var $buttons;
    var $infos;
    if (json['msg'] != "") {
      addButtons($(json['msg']));
      addInfos($(json['msg2']));
    }
    timestamp = json["timestamp"];
    setTimeout("waitForMsg()",1000);
}

addButtons = function($buttons){
  // loop through the button json data
  $buttons.each(function(){
    // look to see if the button already exists
    var existing = $('[value='+$(this).attr("value")+']').length;
    if(!existing){
      // if not, add the button and assign a click handler
      $(this).appendTo('#load_buttons').click(function(){
        //hide all the children of info
        $('#load_info').children().hide();
        //show the info based on the button value
        $('#'+$(this).val).show();
      });
    }
  });
}
addInfos = function($infos){
  //loop through the info json data
  $infos.each(function(){
    // check to see if an info exists
    var existing = $('#'+$(this).attr("id")).length;
    if(!existing){
      //if not, add the info to the list and set it to hidden
      $(this).appendTo('#load_info').hide();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: this looks good, but a lot different than my attempt so sorry for the late response. I am trying to implement it with my prototype; I will leave another comment describing my results.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have an issue generating your JSON in the PHP script:

```
$response['msg']  = $concat;
$response['msg2'] = $concat2;
```

`$concat` and `$concat2` aren't defined anywhere, did you mean to use `$concat_buttons` and `$concat_info` instead?

```
$response['msg']  = $concat_buttons;
$response['msg2'] = $concat_info;
```

In your jQuery, you reference `#load_info .person`, but it doesn't look the divs that PHP builds are of class `person` which might be why your loop isn't finding them.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. However, the live code I am testing doesn't have this error. I renamed the variables for the question post and forgot to rename the statements you pointed out. I've updated my question with your fix. Sorry for the syntax error, but the root problem still remains. I have also re-worded my question to make better sense.